# What is the difference between a circular interval graph and a circular arc graph?

Tags: graph-theory

A circular arc graph is an intersection graph of a set of arcs on a circle such that it has a vertex for every arc in the set and an edge between every pair of vertices corresponding to arcs that intersect.

I do not see how this is different from a circular interval graph.

Bruhn et al. gave the following definition of a circular interval graph:

> Circular interval graphs are defined as follows: Let a finite subset
>   of a circle be the vertex set, and for a given set of subintervals of
>   the circle consider two vertices to be adjacent if there is an
>   interval containing them both.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that circular interval graphs are nothing but proper circular arc graphs. The latter are [circular arc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular-arc_graph) graphs such that no arc properly contains another.